# Laravel Error Calling Member Function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I followed some tutorial on http://laravel.com/docs/ and it just won't work. Here's what I tried:

Role model:

```
<?php

class Role extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'accounts';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

RoleController.php

```
<?php

class RoleController extends BaseController {

    public function get_role()
    {
        $roles = User::find(16)->group_id;

        if ($roles->contains(3))
        {
            echo 'this works';
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('news/index');
        }
    }
}
```

And my route:

```
Route::get('dash', 'RoleController@get_role');
```

And here's my error:

```
Call to a member function contains() on a non-object
```

It says the error is on line:

```
if ($roles->contains(3))
```

Like the contains method is... I don't know hah.

Also, `$roles = User::find(16)->group_id;`
The 16 is the `id` of the account, right? And the `group_id` is the table?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here's the solution, I've changed it in `RoleController.php`:

```
<?php

class RoleController extends BaseController {

    public function get_role()
    {
        $roles = User::find(16)->group_id;

        if (if ($roles == '1')
        {
            echo 'this works';
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('news/index');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do a `print_r($roles)` and see what you get

Comment: I did it like this: `class RoleController extends BaseController {

 public function get_role() {
$roles = User::find(16)->group_id;
print_r($roles);
}

}` and it just displays 1 :p 
Also I tried with the contain method to set it to 1, but it still does that error.

Comment: Your script expects `$roles` to be an object, as shown by your debugging, `$roles` contains `1` (not an object) which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: Aha, got it. But how could I make it a non-object, or whatever does it take to make it works? Should change the method or something?

Comment: Try changing `public function users()` (plural) to `public function user()` (singular) in your `Role` class

Comment: @FDL
Nope, still getting the error.

Comment: Where does `group_id` come from? are you sure it's not `roles`? `$roles = User::find(16)->roles;`

Comment: Thanks for your help, @The Shift Exchange helped me, but he deleted his post haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$roles = User::find(16)->group_id;
```

means you are asking "find user 16, and give me the group_id of that user". This is the "1" that you refer to (in your comments).

Since you have the `group_id` - change

```
if ($roles->contains(3))
```

to

```
if ($roles == '3')
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution, I've changed it in RoleController.php:

```
    <?php
```

class RoleController extends BaseController {

```
    public function get_role() {
$roles = User::find(16)->group_id;

            if (if ($roles == '1')
             {
               echo 'this works';
             } else {

               return Redirect::to('news/index');
                    }
             }
}
```

Comment: Could you update your answer to include *where* you change that code? A bigger snippet (I know you can infer it by reading the question, but it's better if the answer is self-sufficient)